# Compare two HTML sources and display visual differences

Tags: java, javascript, html, comparison

I am trying to show where the two HTML pages differ. I am trying to figure out a way if i can compare the HTML source code of two webpages(almost similar), and show/highlight the differences visually(on UI).

**What I tried:** I thought of taking snapshot of the page and then use [Resemble.js](http://huddle.github.io/Resemble.js/) to compare two images. But that shows very minute differences as well and results are something which is not clear.

I thought of comparing the DOM structure or the source code and then show what or where actually the two pages differ on **UI**.

Is there any way i could achieve this?  I am using [Selenium- Webdriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/) to get the snapshots and the HTML source code.

**EDIT:**

I guess my question was not clear. Actually, i wanted to find out the difference in HTML content for webpages in order to detect A/B tests being performed currently. I first grabbed the html source into a text file and then compared it with previously captured HTML source using [Java-Diff util](https://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/) . This gave me the actual lines which differ in two text files with HTML source.

Now, the problem is, how can i show this difference on UI as in highlighting the areas which i found are different? Hope this would make it more clear.

The below code shows the lines which differ

```
List<String> original = fileToLines("HTML Source diff/originalSource.txt");
    List<String> revised = fileToLines("HTML Source diff/sourceAfterCookieClear.txt");

    // Compute diff. Get the Patch object. Patch is the container for computed deltas.
    Patch patch = DiffUtils.diff(original, revised);

    System.out.println("Printing Deltas\n");
    for (Delta delta : patch.getDeltas()) {
        String revisedText = delta.getRevised().toString();
        String content = revisedText.substring(revisedText.indexOf(" [")+2,revisedText.indexOf("]]"));
        writeTextToFile(content,"difference.html");
    }
```

Any leads in form of code would be helpful.

Comment: I was thinking of any solution programatically

Comment: Have you already solved this problem on your own? I am trying to build something similar, just with a heat-map of code changes, so it is quite interesting for me, if there already exists a solution on which I could at least build on.

Comment: How did you saved the HTML file itself? prettify ? or did you save it a long string using 'driver.getSourcePage'?

Comment: Another easy possibility would be the recheck-web Chrome extension (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/recheck-web-demo/ifbcdobnjihilgldbjeomakdaejhplii). By default it gives you all differences of two websites, including visual or "hidden" ones. But the filter functionality let's you focus on what you really want and marks these in the screenshots.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://lxml.de/api/lxml.html.diff-module.html#htmldiff. Since the question isn't accepting answers, I cannot give a detailed answer, but the documentation should suffice nonetheless.

Comment: There is JavaScript lib [diff2html](https://diff2html.xyz/index.html) that works for browser also.

Answer (score 11):

Use python's [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/difflib.html#difflib.HtmlDiff). For example:

```
import difflib

file1 = open('file1.html', 'r').readlines()
file2 = open('file2.html', 'r').readlines()

htmlDiffer = difflib.HtmlDiff()
htmldiffs = htmlDiffer.make_file(file1, file2)

with open('comparison.html', 'w') as outfile:
    outfile.write(htmldiffs)
```

This will create an html file named `comparison.html` containing the diffs between the two html files `file1.html` and `file2.html`. Here `file1.html` is considered the *source*, or *original version* whichever is more appropriate for your case, and `file2.html` is the *changed version* or *new version*, again, whichever is more appropriate here.

Hope that helps!

Comment: can I save resultant file in rendered HTML format instead of source format?

Comment: @Umair yes you can. The output of `make_file` in `HtmlDiff` *is* rendered HTML. Give it a try. In my example, the file created is named 'comparison.html'

Comment: No dear, it saves `comparison.html` in HTML-source format ... it is not rendered HTML ...

Comment: @Umair What do you mean by rendered HTML? And what do you mean by "HTML-source format"? Also what do you mean by saving in "rendered HTML format"? I have no idea. Can you elaborate, or a link perhaps?

Comment: rendered mean when you click on page it shows a real webpage... but when i click on it it just shows HTML only like `<html><body><p>Text here</p></body</html>`

But i want is `Text here`

Comment: @Umair Take a look at the docs. I think your problem is somewhere else. An html file containing `<html><body><p>Text here</p></body</html>` **cannot but** be rendered in a browser as `Text here`. Are you using django by any chance? If that's the case use `autoescape`. Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35277299/3375713). I am guessing it because I also faced similar problem with django.

Comment: This is how it looks like http://postimg.org/image/k6gwpvqq9/

RAW HTML ... I am not using DJango ... I have python 2.7

Comment: This answer should not be here or accepted at all: the tags and question were java related and the person answered here is referring to a python code.

Comment: @francogrex yeah, I agree now. Looking back at the question again my answer does seem inappropriate. I should try and reopen this, it's an interesting question. BTW, it's not accepted currently. But it received the bounty coz there was no other answer with 2 or more up vote, pity. Also look at the edit history, it was asked in 2013 but bounty was added in 2016!

Comment: @Sнаđошƒаӽ it's no problem as long as it's clearly mentioned - which your above comment now did and clarified. If it could be tagged for python too that would be nice to help those searching for python specific solutions to find it.

Answer (score 2):

Use daisyDiff api
http://code.google.com/p/daisydiff/
You can call this api from a command prompt after your java code returns a difference.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [BackstopJS](https://github.com/garris/BackstopJS) ?

It's not documented but there is a `misMatchThreshold` parameter you can use to hide subtl differences: https://github.com/garris/BackstopJS/issues/52

Answer (score 0):

I assume you would like to diff the two HTML code files. In which case I would like to point you towards the following library:

http://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already gone through this and this tells me where the two HTML source differ, which is fine. I am stuck to a point that, how should I show this difference as UI.  I mean something like- highlighting the element that has the difference or something of the sort.

Comment: It gets far too complicated at this stage, effectively you need to build an engine to parse HTML, then render it on the screen whilst maintaining a mapping to the code. So in your code you can point to an element and your engine will be able to highlight that object intelligently (based on CSS rules i.e. visibility/overlap/0px width). At which point you can do this with 2 HTML pages and get your engine to highlight the differences. Luckily there is already a library that does something like this: http://code.google.com/p/daisydiff/

Comment: Well, I was also thinking about the same as to reach to an element and then apply some CSS rule to highlight it. Yes, I also gone through **daisydiff** as well but that is also giving some exceptions (null pointer in its Main class). Don't understand why. Its just too messy.

Answer (score 0):

You could embed each element from the diff list in a colored div so that it's easily visible

You stated that you have the list of diffs and the before/after HTML documents. If you can determine which HTML document each differenced element came from, then you could look them up by id in the DOM and embed them into a colored div to make it easily visible.

Answer (score -1):

ok you have got the solution always ,
just except one tric. find first id or class in your patch text with a jscript function and focus over the element with jquery. something like below:

for all characters untill find 'id'
var firstIdOfThePatchText = xxx;
$('#firstIdOfThePatchText ').focus...

cheer