# Django, html tags not interpreted

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I am loading a text from the DB of a django project to display it in the template.

In the text stored within the data base, I added some HTML tags but it seems like the browser cannot interprete this html tags.

Here is my template:

```html
<div>
  <!-- body_text = "<strong>Hello</strong> word"  -->
  {{ entry.body_text }} 
</div>
```

And I got the raw text: `<strong>Hello</strong> word` instead of

```html
<strong>Hello</strong> word
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't want your HTML to be escaped, use `safe` filter:

```
{{ entry.body_text|safe }}
```

[django doc about safe filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe).

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this:

```
{% autoescape off %}
    {{ your_html_content }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

#### From django docs for [autoescape](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape):

> Controls the current auto-escaping behavior. This tag takes either
>   **on** or **off** as an argument and that determines whether auto-escaping is in effect inside the block. The block is closed with
>   an **endautoescape** ending tag.
>
> When auto-escaping is in effect, all variable content has HTML
>   escaping applied to it before placing the result into the output (but
>   after any filters have been applied). This is equivalent to manually
>   applying the escape filter to each variable.

As pointed out in the other answer, you can also use `safe` filter which:

> Marks a string as not requiring further HTML escaping prior to output.
>   When autoescaping is off, this filter has no effect.

See here: [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe) filter.

Read more about django template tags and filters: [Django Built-in template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/)